# C# MethodInfo getReturnType

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, void, methodinfo

I created an instance of MethodInfo:

```
MethodInfo theMethod = typeof(Reciever).GetMethod("methodName", parameterTypes);
```

Now I want to know if theMethod's return type is void. How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy:

```
theMethod.ReturnType == typeof(void)
```